# Install Expo application directly on device

Tags: expo, react-native-ios

I would like to install Expo iOS application directly on my device instead of going to review with AppStore.

I been working on an app which is entirely personal application, and I would like to install it directly on my device.

I been using Expo Go for testings, but I want to be able to have it installed on my device as a standalone application that was not published to Appstore.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

1. Connect iPhone via USB
2. Run `expo run:ios` in your expo project, an emulator should come up with your app. You can just ignore it. This was the only way I could find to avoid going through EAS and therefore having to have a $100/year account. Even `build:ios` wanted a paid account.
3. Now that the `ios` directory has been created, open that in Xcode. You should see the phone's name at the top.
4. After it does all its indexing and downloading, you need to set up the signing. First go to `Preferences -> Accounts` and sign in with your apple dev account (doesn't need to be paid)
5. Go `View -> Navigators -> Project -> $app-name -> Signing & Capabilities` and fill in the team and whatever else is there.
6. Press `run` in Xcode, and the app should be built onto your phone!

Some notes:

- You need a paid account for notifications. You can remove the `expo-notifications` dependency for testing on your devices
- I had to change from an nvm installation of node to a brew one.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Go into your Project directory and open a Terminal. Then just type in:

```
expo build:ios
```

Check here:

https://docs.expo.io/distribution/building-standalone-apps

Comment: Question refers to iOS - not an android build.